# I have a custom UICollectionViewCell that was created using an XIB file.How do I get this cell to push another controller onto the stack when tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionviewcell

I can't drag and create a segue in interface builder as this is an XIB file. Basically I have a UICollectionView that has two layouts. The standard layout uses a uses one custom cell and the other layout users another custom cell.

The first custom cell was easy to connect up as it wasn't an XIB file so I just dragged and connected it up to the detail view I wanted to push to when it was tapped. However the second custom cell is the XIB one and there can't be connected up this way.

**This is my collection view cellForRowAtIndexPath method:**

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{

  //      NSLog(@"cellForItemAtIndexPath");

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";
        VAGGarmentCell *cell;

        if ([[_collectionView collectionViewLayout] isEqual: _flowLayout]) {
            cell = [_collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        } else if ([[_collectionView collectionViewLayout] isEqual: _flowLayout2]) {
            cell = [_collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2 forIndexPath:indexPath];
            //       // Detect tap of image View
           UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecogniser = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTapGarmentCellTwoImage:)];
           [gestureRecogniser setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
           [[cell imageView] addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecogniser];
           [[cell imageView] setUserInteractionEnabled: YES];
        }

        [[cell activityIndicator] startAnimating];

        PFFile *userImageFile = [object valueForKey:@"image"];
        [[cell imageView] setFile: userImageFile];
        [[cell imageView] loadInBackground];

        [[cell activityIndicator] stopAnimating];

        [[cell title] setText:[object valueForKey:@"title"]];
        [[cell price] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"£%@ GBP", [object valueForKey:@"price"]]];

        // if database favourites status is equal to one then set highlighted to (yes)
        UIButton *addFavouriteButton = [cell addFavouriteButton];



       BOOL objectFavourited = [object[@"favourite"] boolValue]; // I set this when add fav button is tapped
       [addFavouriteButton setSelected: objectFavourited];


       [addFavouriteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addFavouriteButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

       return cell;
}

- (void)didTapGarmentCellTwoImage:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"garmentDetailSegue" sender:self];
}
```

**This way is giving me an error:**

```
[UITapGestureRecognizer _layoutAttributes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc7f3290'
```

This just seems messy. Is there a better way to do this? Dragging and connecting with the other cell was so much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath: without adding TapGesture on your cell.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if ([[_collectionView collectionViewLayout] isEqual: _flowLayout]) {
    //do  what you want with the other cell selection
} 
else if ([[_collectionView collectionViewLayout] isEqual: _flowLayout2]) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"garmentDetailSegue" sender:self];
}
```

}